# Restrict height of the 'Watched Tags' sidebar widget (same as Ignored)

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags, tag-watching

I favourite/watch a lot of tags on Arqade, mainly due to the nature of tags on that site; every game has it's own tag.

I've noticed however, as I 'watch' more and more tags, that the widget on the sidebar is kinda getting *a bit out of hand*:

[image: Watched tags]

I've started using the wildcard character to combine tags and subsequently reduce it's height, but I can't deny it's just getting unwieldy. Can the Watched Tags widget have the same/similar sort of 'max height' added that the Ignored widget does, with a 'click to view more' or something? E.g.

[image: Watched tags with a 'view more' link/button]

Comment: The ignored tags already do this.

Comment: @user289905 They do? Even better, this should be a quick win then.